# Multiple if statements in a function

Tags: javascript

Why only the first if statement is executed in the else part?

```
function fizzBuzz(input){
    if(typeof(input) !== 'number'){
       
        return 'not a number'
    }
    else{
        if(input % 3 === 0 && input % 5 === 0 ) return 'FizzBuzz';
        if(input % 3 === 0 && input % 5 !==0 ) return 'Fizz';
         if(input % 5 === 0 && input % 3 !==0 ) return 'Buzz';
        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code where you are calling this?

Comment: What are the input you are passing to the function

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: I don't think you understand [how ``return`` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#description). Your first if statement will evaluate to ``true``, return the string ``'first'``, and then exit the function.

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code and it appears to be working.

```
>> fizzBuzz(1)
1
>> fizzBuzz(5)
"Buzz"
>> fizzBuzz(3)
"Fizz"
>> fizzBuzz(15)
"FizzBuzz"
```

What inputs are you using?